# Changing the page URL and get first two letters

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

How can I change page url query and get first two letters . in .htaccess or php

```
http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/index.php?query=Bird
http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/index.php?query=eagle
```

**Like this :**

```
http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/search/bi/bird.html
http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/search/ea/eagle.html
```

**Htaccess code :** 127.0.0.1/site/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?.html$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why do you have `+` after first slash in `/site/`? How are you getting `/site/flowers/index.php?query=Bird` URL? Is it via some form post or a href link?

Comment: @anubhava , Sir .. form post /site/flowers/index.php?query=Bird .... (Address bar)

Comment: .htacces located > ... 127.0.0.1/site/.htaccess

Comment: If it is a form post then I suggest using a JS code to change the URL even before it gets posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Javascript code that you can use for this redirection:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Post Example</title>
<script>
function prettySubmit(form, evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
   var val = form.query.value.toLowerCase();
   window.location =
          form.action + '/' + val.substr(0, 2) + '/' + val.replace(/ /g, '+') + '.html';
   return false;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="flowers/search" onsubmit='return prettySubmit(this, event);'>
   <input type="text" name="query">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then you can have this rule in `site/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([^/.]+)\.html$ index.php?query=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will convert your URLs to:

```
http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/search/bi/bird.html
```

When you perform search using word `bird` in search field.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir @anubhava for your assistance :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?.html$ index.php?query=$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} query=([^/\.]{2})([^/\.]+)
RewriteRule index.php search/%1/%1%2.html [R=301]
```

Then `http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/Bird.html` redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/index.php?query=Bird` which in turn redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/site/flowers/search/Bi/Bird.html`

I'm assuming this is what you want?